# How to uninstall IronPython Tools?

Tags: python, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, ironpython

I wish to install Python Tools for Visual Studio from [here](http://pytools.codeplex.com).

The setup complains about "IronPython Tools feature of IronPython 2.7" and asks me to remove it.

Problem is I cannot find any way to uninstall this feature.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

There are two folders in the extension folder (mine is at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft) namely  "IronPython Tools for Visual Studio" and IronStudio  delete these and it should work.  - Rotimi

Comment: Wow, it's really irritating that you still have to do this when installing the *VS2015* version of the Python tools.

Answer (score 1):

Re-run the IronPython installer and click the Change button.  Then on the feature tree select Will not be installed for the tools feature.

Comment: Can you describe where it failed?  Did you not see the the feature in the feature tree?  Did the uninstall fail?  Or were you unable to install afterwards?  Also, are you using IronPython 2.7 final?

Comment: Sorry, should have been more specific. Yes, this is IronPython 2.7 final. I did see the feature in the feature tree. The uninstall completed with no error messages, but the feature was still there, i.e. if I run the msi again I still see it as installed, and can still access the features in VS.

Comment: Oh, that sucks!  Not sure what's going on there but I'd suggest doing a complete uninstall and then re-install w/o installing the VS tools in that case.

Comment: This did not work for me either. More worryingly, I uninstalled IP2.7 completely, and PTVS still showed this same message. Any ideas?

Comment: I had this problem and tried to uninstall through the MSI and the 2.7.1 installer reported the tools uninstalled, but they were still there.  Went and deleted them myself using Rotimi's advice.

Comment: Worked for me.  I have Iron Python 2.7.1000 installed.  Selected Change then, in the feature tree, selected Tools for Visual Studio and selected "Entire feature will be unavailable" from the context menu.  When Iron Python installer had completed I ran it again and confirmed the Tools for Visual Studio was still showing as unavailable.  Ran the installer for PTVS and it worked fine.  This was PTVS for VS 2010.

Answer (score 1):

This is how it worked for me after I run into the same issue. Re-run the IronPython 2.7 installer and click the Remove button. After it has finished re-run the installer and on the feature tree select Will not be installed for the tools feature.